# LNA circuit: why is the inductor causing a voltage and current drop?

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, dc, bias, lna

I am designing the following circuit whose schematic and testbench I put below:

[image]

I performed a DC bias analysis.

Theoretically, I would expect that at DC the inductor would be a short-circuit and the capacitor would be an open-circuit, so the current on the voltage source to be equal to the current on the drain of thetransistor. What I found is that the current on the source is 30 mA while the drain current of the transistor has only a current of 29.77 mA. I would also expect the drain voltage of the transistor to be 3.3 V, verifying however that it is just 2.821 V so there is almost a 0.5 V voltage drop on the inductor.

Can someone please help me understand how I can justify this? What non-ideality is playing here? Is the inductor actually a small resistor? Where is the current leakage? Is it to the bulk terminal of the inductor?

Answer (score 1):

Your inductor has a resistance of 16 ohms. That seems high. What simulation tool are you using? I don't have enough remaining life to spend decoding your schematic, but it looks like you're modeling some sort of FET as an inductor. I suspect that has some associated series resistance, perhaps you could figure out what's going on there.

Comment: I've verified and this inductor indeed has a 16 ohm DC resistance. I guess the technology is old (this is for uni). For you to have an idea, their 9 nH resistor has twice that value.

Comment: @rfdave it looks like these are on chip planar inductors, so the "wire" cross section is going to be pretty small.